# Deleting backup appendix form file name in multiple files (Linux)

Tags: linux, perl, terminal, debian, file-rename

I recently went from windows to Linux (Debian based) and I imported all my files from a backup drive. The problem is that now all the files are named with the original name + an appendix with the date of the backup inside a pair of brackets.

> **Example:**
>
> *index (2017_12_01 15_56_03 UTC).html*
>
> Instead of *index.html*

How do I **delete** from **all** the files the informations added by the backup?
I am searching for a function that could go trough all the files in a directory and delete the brackets part.

Or is there a way I can reimport without it?

Comment: I think you will be better off asking this question on [superuser](https://superuser.com) or [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com). Over here we are programmers, and expect you to make an attempt to programatically solve your own problem first.

Comment: That said, yes it can be done in Perl with a few lines of code. But I would be scared to run this over all the file system. If it's only your home directory (or Windows user dir) it's probably pretty safe though.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll keep it in mind for next time!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The shell solution, assuming everything after the first `(` should be replaced with `.html`, is

```
for f in *.html; do
  mv "$f" "${f%%\(*}.html"
done
```

which is easily extended to work recursively:

```
find . -name '*.html' |
while read f; do
  mv "$f" "${f%%\(*}.html"
done
```